# Wordpress - Youtube embed not clickable on mobile devices

Tags: wordpress, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

my Wordpress version is 4.6.6
I am adding my youtube videos to my wordpress site, it works correctly on desktop devices but when I open the page from mobile browser, I can see the youtube player and thumbnail of the video but I can not click and play it.

I have tried [ARVE Plugin](https://tr.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-responsive-video-embedder/) , [Youtube Widget Responsive Plugin](https://tr.wordpress.org/plugins/youtube-widget-responsive/) and **oEmbed**, all of them works on desktop but I could't play them on mobile browser (Android and iOS, both of them can't play)

Also I've tried this **youtube embed code** but I failed again.

```
<iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Then I added these attributes to iframe and noting happened.

```
 class="youtube-player" type="text/html"
```

So, where is the problem? I could't see anything wrong. It should work but it is not working.

Comment: It could be something related to CSS like `z-index` or `pointer-events`. If also happens with dev tools in Chrome using the device view, it would be easier to address what is causing the `iframe` being _unclickable_.

Comment: I installed the Chrome dev version on my phone, but nothing happened. I didn't  understand how to detect the problem , my English is not enough to understand what you sad, sorry. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't clears about the position of "class".
I think you are getting problem because of plugins. I would like to suggest you not to use any plugins. Uninstall all the plugins related to YouTube videos and follow the below steps.

There are some [shortcut methods to embed YouTube video (works on mobile too) See here](http://www.wantextra.com/how-to-embed-youtube-video-in-wordpress/). The method you are following is similar to Method 3 in this article.

1. Copy that  code from YouTube video.
2. Go to WordPress post where you want to embed this video.
3. Go to Text Editor and Paste your copied code inside div tag having class "video-container".
4. Save it.
5. Go to "Appearance->Editor" from WordPress left panel.
6. By default, style.css file should be opened. If not, open "style.css" file.
7. Copy the below CSS code as it is.

   ```
       .video-container {
       position:relative;
       padding-bottom: 56.25%;
       padding-top: 25px;
       height: 0;
       }
       .video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       }
   ```
8. Click "Update".
   Your video should become mobile clickable as well as responsive.

Comment: Nope. I could't play it on mobile devices. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I am playing it everywhere and in the same way I have done on my blog. I think you didn't uninstall all youtube related plugins before proceeding to this method

Comment: I disabled plugins but in my opinion, the problem is the wordpress theme. It is not mobile responsive. Thus, the youtube embed loads the desktop player. Is it possible?

Comment: Check the other UI of your site.  They are changing according to device or not.  If changing then your site is responsive.